# Search nodes and taxonomy terms

Tags: search

I need to implement functionality for search nodes and taxonomy terms through one search form and display results in one listing.

I try to use these modules:
1. [Apache Solr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr)
2. [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api)
3. [Search API Solr Search](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr)
4. [Search API multi-index searches](http://drupal.org/project/Search_api_multi)
5. [Search_api_views](http://drupal.org/project/search_api)

I can't make apache solr module add taxonomy terms into index.
It's possible? What I do wrong?
Now my apache solr index only nodes.

I configure apachesolr module https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQa01.png
Also I configure Search API https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPCBK.png

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I do face similar situation and I am trying with http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_term module.

> This module provides basic indexing of the taxonomy terms for the
>   multi entity branch of the Apache Solr Search Integration Module

I will post back my findings soon.

Comment: @Eugene It served my purpose. It indexed the terms in vocabularies chosen from config page. Hope it will help you as well.